# A Swiss Army like module for dealing with HTTP and URLs

Tags: python, http, url

I code a lot of web crawlers and web scrapers and I find myself writing the same functions over and over again. I also find myself having to come to Stack Overflow and find the answer to a question I have had to ask myself a dozen times. Things like "how to supply proxies to requests" or "how to use custom headers with requests" or "how to set the User-Agent in requests" and things of that sort. So I'm writing this module to abstract some of these mundane routines.

**My concerns**

- Is the code pythonic?
- Would this be of use to anybody other than me?
- Are there any bugs?
- Is it ok to have that many methods in a class?
- How are my naming conventions?

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


'''
this module was designed with web scrapers and web crawlers in mind.
I find my self writing these functions all the time. I Wrote this model
to save time.
'''

import requests
import urlparse
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import os
import json
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

class InvalidURL(Exception):
    pass

class URL(object):
    '''Commomn routines for dealing with URLS.
    '''
    def __init__(self, url):
        '''Setup the initial state
        '''
        self.raw_url = url
        self.url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        self.scheme = self.url.scheme
        self.domain = self.url.netloc
        self.path = self.url.path
        self.params = self.url.params
        self.query = self.url.query
        self.fragment = self.url.fragment


    def __str__(self):
        ''' This os called when somthing
        asks for a string representation of the
        url
        '''
        return self.raw_url


    def valid(self):
        """Validate the url.

        returns True if url is valid
        and False if it is not
        """
        regex = re.compile(
            r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://' # http:// or https://
            r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|'
            r'localhost|' #localhost...
            r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
            r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
            r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
        match = regex.match(self.raw_url)
        if match:
            return True


    def unquote(self):
        """unquote('abc%20def') -> 'abc def'."""

        return urllib2.unquote(self.raw_url)


    def quote(self):
        """quote('abc def') -> 'abc%20def'

        Each part of a URL, e.g. the path info, the query, etc., has a
        different set of reserved characters that must be quoted.

        RFC 2396 Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax lists
        the following reserved characters.

        reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
                      "$" | ","

        Each of these characters is reserved in some component of a URL,
        but not necessarily in all of them.

        By default, the quote function is intended for quoting the path
        section of a URL.  Thus, it will not encode '/'.  This character
        is reserved, but in typical usage the quote function is being
        called on a path where the existing slash characters are used as
        reserved characters.
        """
        return urllib2.quote(self.raw_url)


    def parameters(self):
        """
        parse the parameters of the url
        and return them as a dict.
        """
        return urlparse.parse_qs(self.params)


    def secure(self):
        """ Checks if the url uses ssl. """
        if self.scheme == 'https':
            return True


    def extention(self):
        """ return the file extention """
        return os.path.splitext(self.path)[1]


    def absolute(self):
        """ Checks if the URL is absolute. """
        return bool(self.domain)


    def relitive(self):
        """ Checks if the url is relitive. """
        return bool(self.scheme) is False


    def encode(self, mapping):
        """Encode a sequence of two-element tuples or dictionary into a URL query string.

        If any values in the query arg are sequences and doseq is true, each
        sequence element is converted to a separate parameter.

        If the query arg is a sequence of two-element tuples, the order of the
        parameters in the output will match the order of parameters in the
        input.
        """
        query = urllib.urlencode(mapping)
        return urlparse.urljoin(self.raw_url, query)


class Request(object):


    allow_redirects = True
    timeout = 5
    ramdom_useragent = 0
    verify_ssl = False
    session = requests.Session()
    stream = True
    proxies = {}

    def __init__(self, url):
        """ Set the inital state """
        self.agentHeaders = {}
        self.url = URL(url)
        if not self.url.valid():
            raise InvalidURL("{} is invalid".format(url))

    def stream(self, answer):
        self.stream = bool(answer)

    def randomUserAgent(self):
        """ Set a random User-Agent """
        self.setUserAgent(UserAgent().random)


    def allowRedirects(self, answer):
        """ Choose whether or not to follow redirects."""
        self.allow_redirects = bool(answer)


    def setUserAgent(self, agent):
        """ Set the User-Agent """
        self.setHeaders('User-Agent', agent)


    def setHeaders(self, key, value):
        """ Set custom headers """
        self.agentHeaders[key] = value


    def verify(self, answer):
        """ Set whether or not to verify SSL certs"""
        self.verify_ssl = bool(answer)


    def get(self):
        """Sends a GET request"""
        return self.session.get(
            url=self.url,
            headers=self.agentHeaders,
            allow_redirects=self.allow_redirects,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            verify=self.verify_ssl,
            stream=self.stream,
            proxies=self.proxies
            )


    def head(self):
        """ Send a head request and return the headers """
        return self.session.head(
            self.url,
            headers=self.agentHeaders,
            allow_redirects=self.allow_redirects,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            verify=self.verify_ssl,
            proxies=self.proxies
            ).headers


    def options(self):
        """ Send a options request and return the options """
        return self.session.options(
            self.url,
            headers=self.agentHeaders,
            allow_redirects=self.allow_redirects,
            timeout=self.timeout,
            verify=self.verify_ssl,
            proxies=self.proxies
            ).headers['allow']


    def json(self):
        """
        Deserialize json data (a ``str`` or ``unicode`` instance
        containing a JSON document) to a Python object.
        """
        return json.loads(self.text)


    def headerValue(self, value):
        """ Get a value from the headers. """
        return self.headers().get(value)


request = Request('https://www.google.com')
req =  request.get()
```

Comment: Please look for existing relevant site tags before trying to create your own.  We don't need a tag for every specific thing.

Answer (score 4):

Your code feels like an unnecessary duplication of existing things.

(I’m going to skip things alecxe already mentioned)

- Most methods on the `URL` class are one-liners that refer to the raw URL and pass it onto some urlparse/urllib2 function. If you need only one of those functions, it would be better to do `urllib2.unquote(some_url)` than `URL(some_url).unquote()` — in addition to readability, your method creates an object that is very quickly discarded (and calls `urlparse`, the results of which are unused).
- `secure` is misleading — `https` is not the only TLS-using protocol out there
- Typo: `relative`

---

- The `Request` class is again overcomplicating and duplicating code. It exposes only a few features of the library, making it very inflexible. It uses a single session for every request, which means leaking state between requests.
- You still need to type more:

  ```
  request = Request('https://www.google.com')
  req =  request.get()
  # -- versus --
  req = requests.get('https://www.google.com')
  # -- and if you need sessions, it’s still shorter --
  s = requests.Session()
  req = s.get('https://www.google.com')
  ```
- Users still need to interact with requests’ `Response` objects. In fact, after issuing the requests, users will discard your Request object, simply because it’s unnecessary.
- The `json` and `headerValue` methods are broken. (`json` should use `Response.json()`, btw)
- Setter methods (`allowRedirects`, `verify`, `setUserAgent`, `setHeaders`) are unnecessary and considered very bad style in Python. Additionally, the names of `allowRedirects` and `verify` are easy to confuse for `allow_redirects` and `verify_ssl` (the underlying properties)
- It does not make sense to call `.get` then `.post` (or `.get` twice) on the same thing, this is why `requests.get(url)` and `request.Request('GET', url)` explicitly specify the method.

Answer (score 2):

#### Code Style notes

- organize imports in separate groups, have a single line break between the groups, have two newlines after the imports and before the code starts ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))
- have two blank lines between the class definitions, single blank line between class methods, remove extra newlines ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines))
- have your docstrings properly formatted - they should be in triple double quotes, start with a capital letter and end with a dot  ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings))
- naming - use `lower_case_with_underscores` variable and method naming style ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions))

#### Other notes and thoughts

- *Python 3 compatibility* - as of now, the code is Python-2.x only - if you want the code to be re-used by others, think about making it both Python 2 and 3 compatible
- beware of [God objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)
- you can use ["verbose" mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) for your regular expression which might make it even more readable - even though you've done a good job documenting it
- I am not 100% sure about having a `session` instance as a class variable - I think it should better be an instance variable ([differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2714573/771848))
- I think `Request` class requires some explanation - consider adding a docstring

Answer (score 2):

You asked

> Would this be of use to anybody other than me?

Likely you already have automated tests that exercise all the lines of code -- it would be useful to post the tests along with the module. This would help answer questions such as, "have we ever seen callers with a need manipulate Request headers after construction?", leading perhaps to the "setter" code moving into `__init__()`. Consider using an underscore prefix for methods you don't intend to be public.

This identifier has the wrong name:

```
    self.agentHeaders = {}
```

Rather than `agent_headers`, more accurately it would simply be `headers`, since currently the public API offers support for adding arbitrary headers.

Typo: `extention`. This is a typo, plus it's unused: `ramdom_useragent = 0`

Double un-quoting errors are common enough in web code (e.g. https://bugs.python.org/issue2244 ). Your module has an opportunity to immediately offer the caller an exception at that point, making such bugs shallow.